# Weird behavior between the Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, cors

I am doing a site using react. The site is using API  /api/auth/login for logging. But for now the database has problem, so the api returns error 500.

But I got weird issue in Chrome. In Chrome, it shows the CORS error: [image]

This is response of OPTIONS:

[image]

As we saw in response of OPTIONS: the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set to `*`

In Firefox, I can see the response with error 500.

I don't know why Chrome has different behavior.
Please share your thinking.

Thank you.